# To be drafted in, to be drafted for or to be drafted into the army?

Tags: verbs

I'm not sure whether any of these options are valid.
Which one is more common? (US or UK)

> Daniel is drafted in the army.
>
> Daniel is drafted for the army.
>
> Daniel is drafted into the army.

Comment: It is not "drafted in" - that would mean: "he was drafted (for/into something) while in the army".

Comment: How is this not [genref](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drafted+in+the+army%2Cdrafted+for+the+army%2Cdrafted+into+the+army&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrafted%20in%20the%20army%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrafted%20for%20the%20army%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrafted%20into%20the%20army%3B%2Cc0)?

Comment: Waw - this google books ngram viewer just blew my mind, thank you Edwin Ashworth! cool tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Daniel is drafted in the army.* = Daniel is drafted while in "the army"/"military service".

*Daniel is drafted for the army.*  = Daniel is drafted "for the purposes of"/"on behalf of" the army.

*Daniel is drafted into the army.* = Daniel is drafted into "the army"/"military service" - I think this is closest to what you intended.

Comment: Cool! Thank you - with explanation for every sentence.